# Something overriding PHP.ini setting, not htaccess. Need suggestion

Tags: php

I'm struggling to find where a specific PHP.ini setting is being overridden in my AWS Linux 2 instance with PHP 7.3.11 and httpd 2.4.  I am trying to set

mysqli.allow_local_infile = On

I have set it correctly in the PHP.ini file as you can see here (and restarted httpd)

[Here's my PHP.ini file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dVf3.png)

I then used grep to check the setting from the command line:

[Shows the allow_local_infile setting is On](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt5Af.png)

But when I go to phpinfo.php that I have set up on my httpd webserver it shows allow_local_infile = Off:

[phpinfo.php shows allow_local_infile = Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htfeu.png)

Any suggestions where something else could be set that would override?  It's not in an htaccess file because I don't have it enabled at the moment.  Plus I don't believe allow_local_infile the value can be overridden at the htaccess level.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you check in your phpinfo.php that the path to php.ini is correct ?

Comment: Thanks Swisstone.  Good question.  I have checked several times and it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that answer to the question is that I needed to restart the AWS EC2 instance.  Simply restarting httpd didn't do it.  Apparently the value was cached somewhere and the restart was needed to fix it.

When all else fails, restart the AWS instance, not just service.

Comment: Were you using fpm or fcgi? Restarting httpd wouldn't pick up the changes if so.